# MySQL: Query from Unknown Number of Tables

Tags: mysql, logging, ejabberd

Here's what I'm trying to do. I'm using ejabberd with mod_logdb. All conversations are logged to a table in the database tagged with the date.

ex: logdb_messages_2010-7-17_server_node

What I'm trying to do is write a search that will look in all these tables without hitting the DB too much.  I'd like to create a view that takes all the data in the table so I can just hit that.

Problem is there may be days that have no logs and, of course, days before we started logging.

Is there a way I can somehow use a wildcard to snag these from MySQL? My other other though would be writing a daily cron job to recreate the view I'd need.

Comment: Can I ask why the database design doesn't just use a date column to store the date? That would make things a hundred times simpler.

Comment: Good question. It'd make my life a whole lot easier right now. As it is, mod_logdb stores it this way. I think it's to make it easier to keep only X amount of days worth of logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, that's a Sr. antipattern.

You should query the [information schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html), unless you can control the schema and avoid the mistake in the first place.

If you cannot, you have to dynamically generate a prepared statement.

This is an example:

http://jayant7k.blogspot.com/2008/02/mysql-stored-procedures-dynamic-tables.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Merge engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/merge-storage-engine.html) to simplify selection of data from multiple tables.
Views don't improve performance. You have to optimize your queries and add necesarry indexes to improve performance. Sometimes a redesigning of schema is a sollution too.